# AS3 - Using Tween on integer?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Not been using the Tween functions before, so I'd like a little help.

I want to tween between two integers.

Example:
I buffer 360 frames (images).

I want to skip to frame 100 (from frame 1), but I want to use ease to make it look better.

All I need is to tween an integer that I will use for the current image displayed.

---

So far so good, but I'm not getting how to update my image in the tween:

```
        public function timerEvent(event:TimerEvent):void{
            TweenLite.to(this, 2, {_currentFrame: 50, ease:Strong.easeOut}); 

            if (_currentFrame>=358) _currentFrame -= 359;
            if (_currentFrame<0) _currentFrame += 359;
            var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(buffer[_currentFrame+1]);
            myBitmap.smoothing = true;
            imageBuffer.data = myBitmap;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously recommend using Greensock's TweenLite and TweenMax libraries over the built in Tweening functions.

http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

The beauty of these is that you can tween any numeric property of an object, and apply easing, and you can even tween frames of a MovieClip directly by using the Frames plug that is built into TweenMax:

```
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.easing.Strong;

TweenMax.to(this,2,{frame:100,ease:Strong.easeOut});
```

To Tween a counter value is just as easy, and because it doesn't require the Frames plugin you can use the lighter TweenLite:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.Strong;

var counter:int = 0;

TweenLite.to(this,2,{counter:100,ease:Strong.easeOut});
```

**Edit to include new code**

As the tween runs you can capture an update event which lets you perform actions on the current values of your parameters.  You could then do something like this:

```
TweenLite.to(this, 2, {_currentFrame: 50, ease:Strong.easeOut, onUpdate:updateCallback}); 

function updateCallback():void
{
    var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(buffer[_currentFrame+1]); 
    myBitmap.smoothing = true; 
    imageBuffer.data = myBitmap;
}
```

Comment: You will need to activate the plugin first, though, by writing `TweenPlugin.activate([FramePlugin]);`.

Comment: Not with TweenMax, it's activated automatically. You would have to activate it when using TweenLite.

Comment: I'm going to tween an integer which I then use to define what frame I should jump to (as my frames are buffered to an array in memory for fast access).

I'm looking into tweenLite now :)

Comment: Thanks. But every time I update my variable (_currentFrame) I need to update the image to match the _currentFrame number.

I edited my post to show the code..

Comment: @stian - updated again to demonstrate executing code every time the value is modified.

Comment: I figured it out just when you posted, but thanks a lot for your help mate! =D

Comment: Since I've already got your attention.
Is there any way to determine which way it should count?

My 360 images is a loop, so when it comes to the last image it continues from frame 1..

I'd like to tween to the closest frame. So if I'm at frame 340 and want to go to frame 10, the best would be to tween through 359 to 10, instead of backwards to 10..

Comment: @Stian -  You should probably post that as a new question because I imagine there would be more than one approach.